# Are female super heroes often referred to by their common names?

Tags: comics, names, super-hero

I know from my childhood I heard of Jean Grey before I heard of her as Marvel Girl. Emma Frost is rarely referred to as The White Queen.

Is this confirmation bias on my part, or is this a real trend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's confirmation bias.  There's many examples where the costumed version gets used much much more:

- Wonder Woman
- Ms Marvel
- Rogue
- Catwoman
- She-Hulk
- Magik

They're just counter-examples that I thought of off the top of my head.

For those who are more commonly referred to by their normal name, it's often due to their forgoing of previous identities/personas/aliases:

- Emma Frost's "White Queen" persona was when she was a villain.  Now that's she's been part of the X-Men semi-continuously, that persona is inappropriate and no longer relevant.
- Similarly, Jean Grey transitioned away from Marvel Girl through other personas related to the Phoenix, resulting in use of her name rather than one particular persona.
- Kitty Pryde is a third example, but again, she has had at least three aliases according to Wikipedia - Ariel, Sprite and now Shadowcat.

Comment: Hank Pym is another good example for the guys.  He's had several aliases (Ant-Man, Giant-Man, Goliath, and Yellowjacket) so he's  often referred to by his real name.  Reed Richards is another example.  He's almost never referred to as Mr. Fantastic.